# API or context menu to set the working directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there an option/extension to right-click on a folder and set it as a working directory?
Does `VSCode` provide such API to modify it easily?

Would it be complicated to implement such an extension?

Comment: There is the right-click option to "Open in Terminal".

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the hint, however it doesn't help me because I'm adding some buttons through an extension in the status bar and the buttons execute a script based on the content of the folder (that's why I need to have an option to change the "current folder"

Answer (score 1):

to provide a menu on right-click, you can use contributes.menus , I think you will use explorer/context command id https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus

I think you should be able to reuse the "Open Folder..." action from the top-level menu "File". The code for it seems to be https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/60fe7184a7b43564c4a8516242197a111aad3f4d/src/vs/workbench/browser/actions/workspaceActions.ts#L39

I would say it shouldn't be a complicated extension.

regards,

EDIT: the Open folder command is listed in documentation vscode.openFolder https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands#commands